# Proof truth is absolute and not relative

Tags: epistemology, proof, deduction, relativism

First of all, I want to point out I am not any expert in philosophy, so this question is not based in no further readings, but only my own knowledge in logic.

Imagine I want to proof the truth is relative and that will lead to a contradiction:

- Premise: The truth is relative.
- Deduction: If the truth is relative,    there are neither pure true nor
  false statements.
- Demonstration:    Therefore, to affirm that the truth is absolute is
  neither true nor    false, therefore, it can be affirmed that the
  truth is absolute,    contradicting the premise.
- Conclusion: Therefore, the truth must be    absolute.

Now, imagine I want to proof the truth is absolute and that will not lead to any contradiction:

- Premise: The truth is absolute.
- Deduction: If the truth is absolute,    there are pure true and
  false statements.
- Demonstration:    Therefore, to affirm that the truth is relative is
  true or false, but, now it cannot be affirmed that the
  truth is relative, because it is purely false (if it was true, we would be accepting relativity in the premise, which we do not). And if we say truth is absolute, that is the premise.
- Conclusion: Therefore, the truth IS    absolute (which does not lead to any contradiction).

What is it wrong in my proof? I am sure there must be lots of ideas I am missing.

(Note that my sense of relativity does not refer to a disparity of opinions that may exist in politics, but, for example, truths regarding the universe; in the sense, for example, of Ayn Rand's absolute truth as opposed to relative truths of other classical philosophers).

Comment: We generally do not assess original ideas here. What I can say, though, is this: truth in the pragmatically interesting sense is not a logical, but an *epistemological* problem. So the question should not be whether there **is** an absolute truth, but whether or how we can **know** it. And there, we can say that there cannot be any absolute **standard** for truth since we cannot know whether this standard is **true** itself, ie. any positing of truth is arbitrary/relative.

Comment: Sorry, will I delete the post then? Thanks for the answer anyway!

Comment: You have not sufficiently expressed the argument in correct form as done in Philosophy. You need to look up how to do it correctly. Secondly if your premises were all.true them the conclusion MUST BE TRUE by definition.  Thirdly, you would prove the entire field of mathematics is worthless as well as most other academic topics. Fourthly, truth has two basic categories in epistemology: contingent & objective. You don't seem to be aware of this FACT.  If you were you would not think the way you do. Finally if all truth were absolute there would be no contingencies. Look up contingent truth.

Comment: I come from the world of verification in CS and it is usually to stand some premises that can lead to a contradiction (as they can be inconsistent with each other): i.e. we have proven a statement is false by contradiction. Anyway, I have to read more about that contigency concept. Thanks!

Comment: If we agree with "If the truth is relative, there are neither true nor false statements", then also the statement "The truth is relative" is neither true nor false. Now we have a problem: what is the role in a deduction of a premise that is neither true nor false?

Comment: "Therefore, to affirm that the truth is absolute is neither true nor false, therefore, it can be affirmed that the truth is absolute, contradicting the premise." Not clear... if it is neither true nor false, the affirmation that the truth is absolute does not contradict it.

Comment: Of truth is relative, then your "Demonstration" is clearly false.